# Excel range loop with variable in name

Tags: html, excel, html-table, vba

I have a function that will parse text and cell values to make code for an HTML table.

Here's my code:

```
Function Html(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Head As Boolean) As String
' this function will take columns of data and properly format them for html table
Dim retVal As String
Dim i, j, p As Integer
p = 1
'if ranges doesn't contains one column and same rows count - return #VALUE error
If Rng1.Rows.count <> Rng2.Rows.count Or _
    Rng1.Columns.count <> 1 Or Rng2.Columns.count <> 1 Then
    Html = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

retVal = ""

For j = 1 To 2

If Head = True Then
retVal = retVal & "<th>" & Rng1.Cells(1, j)& "</th>"
  If j = 2 Then
    retVal = retVal & "<th>" & Rng2.Cells(1, j) & "</th>"
  End If
p = 2
End If

retVal = retVal & "<tr>"

For i = p To Rng1.Rows.count
    retVal = retVal & "<td>" & Rng & j & .Cells(i, 1) & "</td>"

Next i

retVal = retVal & "</tr>"
Next j


Html = "<table>" & retVal & "</table>"
End Function
```

The problem is I want to cycle through the two ranges. The ranges are called `Rng1` and `Rng2`. I want to combine :Rng" and the loop identifier `j` to make `Rng1.Cells(i,1)` but since it's in the middle of that object I'm not sure how to combine it.

Any help on this?

Comment: Are you trying to put the two ranges side by side in a single html table? In other words - do you want to process them row by row?

Comment: yea, two rows of data was what I was after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to do now. You can create an array of range objects:

```
dim rangeArray
set rangeArray = array(Rng1, Rng2)
```

and use it like this:

```
retVal = retVal & "<td>" & rangeArray(j).Cells(i, 1) & "</td>"
```

Comment: That's a good approach... Thanks! Always looking to lean down my code.

Answer (score 0):

I added an if statement into the code to make it refer to the Rng2 and it resulted in the correct output.

However, if anyone can tell me how to combine within a object that would be helpful.

```
Function Html(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Head As Boolean) As String
' this function will take columns of data and properly format them for highcharts scatter pairs
Dim retVal As String
Dim i, j, p As Integer
p = 1
'if ranges doesn't contains one column and same rows count - return #VALUE error
If Rng1.Rows.count <> Rng2.Rows.count Or _
    Rng1.Columns.count <> 1 Or Rng2.Columns.count <> 1 Then
    Html = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

retVal = ""

For j = 1 To 2

If Head = True Then
retVal = retVal & "<th>" & Rng1.Cells(1, 1) & "</th>"
  If j = 2 Then
    retVal = retVal & "<th>" & Rng2.Cells(1, 1) & "</th>"
  End If
p = 2
End If

retVal = retVal & "<tr>"

For i = p To Rng1.Rows.count
    retVal = retVal & "<td>" & Rng1.Cells(i, 1) & "</td>"
    If j = 2 Then
    retVal = retVal & "<td>" & Rng2.Cells(i, 1) & "</td>"
    End If
Next i

retVal = retVal & "</tr>"
Next j

'remove last comma
If retVal <> "" Then retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1)

Html = "<table>" & retVal & "</table>"
End Function
```